# Could Harry have contacted Dumbledore with a Chocolate Frog card?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

Chapter 33 of *Deathly Hallows* makes it clear that Dumbledore has a portrait that shares his memories and chapter 6 of the first book shows us that Dumbledore's portrait in the Chocolate Frog cards can come and go, just like a normal portrait.

Does this mean that all of Harry's angst about wanting to contact Dumbledore in *Deathly Hallows* could've been solved by buying some chocolate?

Comment: I don't think so? That would mean that there's a single "Dumbledore entity" for every single portrait, chocolate frog card, photo, etc, etc, which seems... improbable.

Comment: given how we see Phineas Nigelus's portrait(s) behave in book 5 & 7 - good question

Comment: If he can buy it from someone, maybe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Dumbledore’s chocolate frog card is a different depiction than his portrait. It is “more of a fleeting snapshot – which is still sentient in a smaller way”, according to [Wizarding World](https://www.wizardingworld.com/features/how-do-magical-portraits-actually-work):

> According to J.K. Rowling, the more powerful you are, the more ‘real’ your portrait can be, and if you sit down with your portrait and spend more time with it, the more accurate a portrayal of yourself it will hold. This is why Albus Dumbledore’s portrait is so lifelike, while his Chocolate Frog card, which also holds his image, is more of a fleeting snapshot – which is still sentient in a smaller way.

It’s not shown that these cards can talk but if they did, I would expect them to be limited to catchphrases more than useful intelligence.

Answer (score 0):

No.
This is mostly conjecture but there is a difference between pictures and portraits. A picture is a snapshot of a time not of the person. Pictures cannot talk. Harry’s picture book that he gets from Hagrid doesn’t talk to him, even though it is his parents. There is never a point in any of the books where a picture talks.

Comment: The paintings can talk which are pictures, what evidence do you that there’s a difference between the card and the paintings for why it won’t be able to talk?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The evidence is that it never happens. The only time anything talks is if it’s painted and the chocolate frog cards are not painted.